# How to pass vec<pubkey> from solana web3 to smart contract

Tags: anchor, web3.js

One of the argument for my smart contract function is vec how do I pass this data type from my frontend using solana-web3js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass them in the [remaining_accounts](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/context/struct.Context.html#structfield.remaining_accounts)

> Remaining accounts given but not deserialized or validated. Be very careful when using this directly.

**anchor**

```
let accounts = ctx.remaining_accounts;
```

**javascript**

what you need is `.remainingAccounts([])`

```
    const tx = await program.methods
      .Initialize(new anchor.BN(10000000))
      .remainingAccounts(
        [{ pubkey: payer.publicKey, isWritable: false, isSigner: false }],
      )
      .accounts({
        payer: payer.publickey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        tokenProgram: splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .rpc();
    console.log('Your transaction signature', tx);
  });
```